# Overriding a private function, how is it different from protected?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In the following program, if GetPart() was made protected instead of private,  would there be a difference to outside (derived) classes or additional member functions within these classes? i.e. is there a compilation error that could be caused by having this as private that wouldn't exist if the function was protected in the base class?

I discovered that it was possible to override private virtual functions recently, which surprised me. Semantically this seems (to me) to be the job of protected, rather than private.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual void runFn() { GetPart(); }

private:
    virtual void GetPart() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}

private:
    virtual void GetPart() override { std::cout << "GETPART RUN" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.runFn();
    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/S9681V to show that the line does get run, as the function gets overriden properly.

Comment: overriding private virtual functions is sometimes a "[feature](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#private-virtuals)".

Comment: Side note: You also can overload/hide private functions, you just can't call the hidden one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This topic creates a lot of confusion: even though subclasses are allowed to override virtual private member functions, they are not allowed to call them.

Currently, this would not compile ([demo 1](http://ideone.com/vjjd74)):

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
private:
    virtual void GetPart() override {
        // This line would not compile
        A::GetPart();
        std::cout << "GETPART RUN" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Making `GetPart()` function protected would let the above code compile without an issue, but it would require you to provide a definition ([demo 2](http://ideone.com/EhDNNS)).

This is the only difference.

Comment: Just to underscore: the problem is **only** the **access specifier** (private or protected). The fact that the function is virtual has nothing to do with it -- you can't call a private member function from a derived class (absent some perversion like making the derived class a friend of the base class).

Comment: This is very confusing to me and defies the whole purpose of private members. Suppose I'm not the author of `class A` and all I know about it, is its interface, and suppose I want create a subclass of `class A` say `class B` in which I accidentally override a private function member (I'm not aware of its existence), what I will get is a different and unexpected behavior from the public interface.